# com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment can not Resolve in com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0

Tags: android, google-api

i updated the com.google.android.gms:play-services-location to 9.0.2 to 9.4.0 everything is fine but unable the Resolve the PlaceAutocompleteFragment.Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these in the build gradle .

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used the google Map services. Follow the following Steps.

Add below code in dependencies.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Now add the following code in XML.

```
<fragment
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Go to your Activity and implements it with OnMapReadyCallback, like given below.

```
public class DealDetailsScreen extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

Above change will give you the error. Add the following code and the error will be resolved automatically.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}
```

Then write the following code in OnCreate function.

```
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

For further help, use this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) and don't forget the manifest permission and Google Map Api Approval.

Answer (score 0):

implement these two libraries in your `build.gradle` file 

    `api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'`